# ui-view is not rendering the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is how it goes

**layout.cshtml** contains

```
<body ng-controller="applicationCtrl">
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

**Index.cshtml** contains (which gets rendered to layout.cshtml)

```
<div>
    <div class="row" header ng-show="showHeader"></div>
</div>
<nav-bar ng-show="showMenu"></nav-bar>
<div ui-view></div>
```

**application.js** contains

```
myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login'); //default route
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
         url: '/home',
         templateUrl: 'Client/Modules/application/views/home.htm',
     })
     .state('home.interstatus', {
            url: '/interstatus',
            templateurl: 'Client/Modules/interStatus/views/interStatus.htm',
        })
```

**home.htm** contains

```
//some code (lets say <h1>Hello World.I am getting rendered to ui-view in index.htm successfully</h1>)
<div ui-view></div>
```

**interStatus.htm** contains

```
<h1>Why am I not getting rendered to ui-view in home.htm ??</h1>
```

In my login code there is something like

```
if ($state.current.name == 'login') {
    $state.transitionTo('home.interstatus');
}
```

when I login to my application I can see a header, navbar and even content in home.htm(Hello world....),but not the content in interStatus.htm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to work as expected in a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/hTuP11uRpqQBh4Zee3a9?p=preview) - are you sure interStatus.htm is loaded successfully?

Comment: @Brad Barber problem is that templateurl  syntax in 'home.interstatus' state is supposed to be templateUrl. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled templateUrl in the home.interstatus state.